# T-SQL query part of xml

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005, xquery

My table @T have a XML column xmlcol on SQL Server 2005. I want to query all the rows where certain node contains a particular value.

```
declare @T table(xmlcol Xml)
insert into @T values('
<root>
<items>
    <item>
        <x1>
            <id>12345678</id>
        </x1>
        <x2>
            <count>12</count>
        </x2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <x1>
            <id>99999999</id>
        </x1>
        <x2>
            <count>10</count>
        </x2>
    </item>
</items>
</root>')

select
[xmlcol].query('/root/items/item')
from @T
where
[xmlcol].exist('/root/items/item/x1/id[contains(.,"12345678")]') = 1
```

This query shows all , but I need only show ONE , like this:

```
<item>
  <x1>
    <id>12345678</id>
  </x1>
  <x2>
    <count>12</count>
  </x2>
</item>
```

I found similar question, but with values only, and I am not able to rewrite query for show nodes.
Is it possible to select part of xml which I need?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of the query you're using is something like

```
SELECT
"all nodes from XML document matching XPath expression"
WHERE
"there is one node in XML document matching XPath expression"
```

You can completely skip the `WHERE` clause, but move its content into an XPath predicate. XPath predicates set filters to axis steps, imagine them as some kind of node test. You might want to keep the `WHERE` clause to avoid empty results (in case some column has no matches at all).

```
select
[xmlcol].query('/root/items/item[x1/id[contains(.,"12345678")]]')
from @T
```

Try the query on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25977/0).

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but I forget namespace. If I use namespace with prefix and another namespace without prefix, query returns empty results. Query is here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1c06/147/0

Comment: Seems reasonable. I think I already saw some version declaring the namespaces outside of XQuery in the SQL, but I'm not sure of that. As this works it's totally fine (and the XQuery way).